# How did Twitter choose their character limit?

Tags: input, text, mobile-text-entry

Twitter posts are limited to 140 "characters", which turns out to mean [code points](https://dev.twitter.com/basics/counting-characters) in UTF8 ([not the only or even most intuitive measure](http://utf8everywhere.org)). Was this determined by a (likely outdated) technical limitation, or is there a published UX rationale?

Comment: I contend that this question is not quite the same as https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/107324/why-does-twitter-limit-tweets-to-140-characters-why-this-number-what-are-pros .  This question specifically asks about why the "character" limit counts *UTF-8 code points*, which the other question (and answer) does not address *at all*.  At any rate, [Twitter explains the rationale for how the limit is measured](https://dev.twitter.com/basics/counting-characters).